# R: Warning message: In Ops.factor(data1$Quality, " ") : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors

Tags: r

I am trying to extract list whose % greater than 85% in R

```
       Verified.count   Overturned.count       Quality        Velocity
1            571               65              88.62%         44.56 

2              37                3              91.89%         76

3              NA               NA              #DIV/0!        #DIV/0!

4              24                7              70.83%        50.87

5              52                3              94.23%        39.79


command -> data1[data1$Quality > "94.23%", ]
```

> Warning message:
>
> In Ops.factor(data1$Quality, "94.23%") : ‘>’ not meaningful for
>   factors

Results

```
Verified.count Overturned.count Quality Velocity

NA              NA             < NA >             < NA > 

NA              NA             < NA >             < NA >

NA              NA             < NA >             < NA > 

NA              NA             < NA >             < NA >

NA              NA             < NA >             < NA >
```

Any suggestions how to use this command to operate with % values.

Comment: Can you please share data using `dput`?

Comment: i uploaded the file through   data1<-read.csv(file.choose(), header = TRUE) .Do you want me to share with you? please share your mailId

Comment: Use `dput(head(df))` to add data to your question. Copy and paste whatever it outputs into your **question.**

Comment: The message seems clear enough. The `Quality` variable is stored as a factor. You need to either import it correctly to begin with or convert it to numerical.

Comment: i changed the quality variable to numeric  as -:xyz<-  data1[, c(6)] <- sapply(data1[, c(6)], as.numeric)       but quality values are getting changed like >
 >xyz  >[1] 11 16 10  9  1  5 18 12  8 17 19 13 20  4  2 15  7 14  2  6  3  2

Answer (score 0):

i removed the % sign from the column quality as -> Quality1<-as.numeric(sub("%", "", data1$Quality))     after that could perform any operations on new quality1 column.